# Maento2 Rest Api for Categories

Tags: magento2, category, rest-api

Is there any API to get all categories detail with images as well?
I am using the below API but it won't return image information

```
/rest/default/V1/categories
```

Answer (score 1):

Using postman:

```
{{magento_url}}rest/default/V1/categories/list?searchCriteria[pageSize]=100&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

with bearer token method on my local, I was able to find the image data. See screenshot below

[image]

Comment: But in this API we didn't know what exactly the page size will be

Comment: if you don't know, is there any problem with giving a big number 9999?

Comment: No, but actually i want the json sequence like the one in  /rest/default/V1/categories

Comment: ok, in this case, the Magento API does not do what you need so I imagine you only solution is to write your own custom API end point?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom API.

I created a custom API to see the product details with productID.
Below is the code for that. You can make changes to it and customize it to show you the category details and its image.

In my example, My vendor is **M2** and my module is **Apis**.

> Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'M2_Apis', __DIR__);
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="M2\Apis\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="M2\Apis\Model\ProductRepository" />
    <preference for="M2\Apis\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="M2\Apis\Model\Data\Product" />
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="M2_Apis" />
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V2/product/getProductsById/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="M2\Apis\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="getProductsById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

> Vendor/Module/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace M2\Apis\Api;

use Magento\TestFramework\Exception\NoSuchActionException;

interface ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return \M2\Apis\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws NoSuchActionException
     */


    public function getProductsById(int $id);
}
```

> Vendor/Module/Api/Data/ProductInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace M2\Apis\Api\Data;



interface ProductInterface{

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int;

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setId($id);

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSku(): string;

    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSku($sku);

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name);

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription(): string;

    /**
     * @param string $description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDescription($description);

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice(): string;

    /**
     * @param string $price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPrice($price);

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getImages(): array;

    /**
     * @param string[] $productImagesArray
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setImages($productImagesArray);
}
```

> Vendor/Module/Helper/ProductHelper.php

This class is used as a helper class for product price and images.

```
<?php

namespace M2\Apis\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data;

class ProductHelper{

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $priceHelper;

    /**
     * @param Data $priceHelper
     */
    public function __construct(Data $priceHelper)
    {
        $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $price
     * @return float|string
     */
    public function formatPrice($price){
        return $this->priceHelper->currency($price,true,false);
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProductImagesArray($product){

        $images = $product->geTMediaGalleryImages();
        $imagesArray = array();
        foreach ($images as $image){
            $imagesArray[] = $image->getUrl();
        }
        return $imagesArray;
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/Model/ProductRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace M2\Apis\Model;

use M2\Apis\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use M2\Apis\Helper\ProductHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\TestFramework\Exception\NoSuchActionException;

class ProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface{

    /**
     * @var ProductInterfaceFactory
     */
    private ProductInterfaceFactory $productInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductHelper
     */
    private ProductHelper $productHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param ProductInterfaceFactory $productInterfaceFactory
     * @param ProductHelper $productHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ProductInterfaceFactory $productInterfaceFactory,
        ProductHelper $productHelper
    )
    {
        $this->productInterfaceFactory = $productInterfaceFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getProductsById(int $id)
    {
        $productInterface = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();
        try {
            //echo ("inside");
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
            $productInterface->setId($product->getId());
            $productInterface->setSku($product->getSku());
            $productInterface->setName($product->getName());
            $desc = $product->getDescription();
            $desc = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $desc);
            $productInterface->setDescription($desc ? strip_tags($desc) : "");
            $productInterface->setPrice($this->productHelper->formatPrice($product->getPrice()));
            $productInterface->setImages($this->productHelper->getProductImagesArray($product));
            return $productInterface;
        }
        catch (NoSuchActionException $e){
            throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField("id",$id);
        }
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/Model/Data/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace M2\Apis\Model\Data;

use M2\Apis\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Tests\NamingConvention\true\string;

class Product extends DataObject implements ProductInterface{

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() : int
    {
        return $this->getData('id');
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        return $this->setData('id',$id);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSku() : string
    {
        return $this->getData('sku');
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setSku($sku)
    {
        return $this->setData('sku',$sku);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->getData('name');
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        return $this->setData('name',$name);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return $this->getData('description');
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        return $this->setData('description',$description);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice() : string
    {
        return $this->getData('price');
    }

    /**
     * @param string $price
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        return $this->setData('price',$price);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getImages() : array
    {
        return $this->getData('images');
    }

    /**
     * @param string[] $productImagesArray
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImages($productImagesArray)
    {
        return $this->setData('images',$productImagesArray);
    }
}
```

Following is the result obtained from *Postman*.
[image: Getting product information using Postman]